# Can't deserialize an ASP.NET viewstate in Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, viewstate

Here's the Base64-encoded viewstate I'm trying to deserialize: https://pastebin.com/VQxvyUGS

…and here's the code I'm attempting to deserialize it with:

```
string test = (content of the linked paste)
var losFormatter = new LosFormatter();
var viewState = losFormatter.Deserialize(test);
```

My program crashes on the last line with a NullReferenceException and I have no idea why. Yesterday, the same code worked just fine on Windows, using the real .NET framework. This is on macOS 10.12.6 in Xamarin Studio with Mono 5.2.0.

Is this a bug in Mono itself?

Comment: Binary serialization is different between .Net and Mono depending upon what you are using to serial/deserial, are you serializing on .Net and trying to deserialize on Mono? And if so, what methods are your using?

Comment: The viewstate is coming from an ASP.NET-powered website being served from IIS on some version of Windows. I'm trying to deserialize the data on a Debian server using Mono. Is there really no way to do this?

Comment: Add some sample code to your question from your .Net implementation that are you using to produce the serialization along with the `Deserialize` method you are using.

Comment: It's not my website, so there's no code to post. I only know it's an IIS-powered site because one of the headers says so.

Comment: What code is in the `Deserialize` that you are calling?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using the bog-standard implementation that Mono provides.